# Ideal Generated by $H\cup K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

If $H$ and $K$ are ideals of a ring $R$, what are the elements of $\langle H\cup K\rangle$? What I am trying to ask is that how does its element look?

Comment: $h+k$ (can you prove it?)

Comment: Actually I'm trying to show that $H+K=\langle H\cup K\rangle$. However, the inclusion $\langle H\cup K\rangle\subseteq H+K$ is the one I can't show.

Comment: Hint: $\langle X\rangle\subseteq I$ iff $X\subseteq I$.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle H \cup K \rangle$ is the ideal generated by $H \cup K$, so it is finite linear combinations of elements from $H$ or $K$.  So an arbitrary element must look like $r_1h_1 + 
\cdots +r_nh_n + s_1k_1 + \cdots + s_mk_m$ where $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, $r_i \in R$, $h_i \in H$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ and $s_i\in R$, $k_i \in K$ for $1\leq i \leq m$.

Can you take it from there?